# JPA　@Inheritance with parent and child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I'm new to EJB JPA.
I'm confused in @Inheritance with parent and child.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owner", catalog = "estate")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="ownerType",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("owner")
public class Owner extends UUIDSupport implements 

UserDetails,java.io.Serializable{
....
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ownerInCommittee")
public class OwnerInCommittee extends Owner {
....
}

CREATE TABLE `owner` (
  `id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCard` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `duty` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, // OwnerInCommittee 
  `ownerType` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Now I want to find 'owner' in the DB,than change it to 'OwnerInCommittee'.
Because java can't force change a parent to child. 
Should I find 'owner' in DB , copy properties into a new 'OwnerInCommittee',than

delete owner in DB . after that PERSIST the new  'OwnerInCommittee'.

Is there a better way?

Comment: refer this.. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritence-table-per-hierarchy-mapping/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure Java there is not a better way. You can of course update the DiscriminatorColumn column in database, but it seems a little bit "hacky". here is a solution on a similar question;
[How to change Entity type in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744520/how-to-change-entity-type-in-jpa)